# How to Store ID in Child Table of the Added String Value in PHP Table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to ask how to insert an ID to the child table when I add a string value to the php table. Like for example:

I have a database called db and its corresponding tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1` (
`id1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fname` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `test1` (`id1`, `fname`) VALUES
(1, 'Mary');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test2` (
`id2` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id2`),
KEY `id1` (`id1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `test2`
ADD CONSTRAINT `test2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id1`) REFERENCES `test1` (`id1`);
```

Table test1 contains the existing data, and table test2 is the child table wherein added datas are to be stored from the php.

And also the php code, assume its connected to the database:

```
<body>
<div style="text-align: center">
<form action="test2.php" method="POST">
<?php
include('connect.php');
$query = "SELECT fname FROM test1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="select1">
<?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['fname']; ?>">
<?php echo $line['fname'];
?>
</option>
<?php }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="secret" />
</form>
<table border="1" width="200" id="sample" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
enter code here
<th> ID </th>
<th> Name </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr class="record" height="100">
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

test1.php

In my php code example, I have the dropdown menu containing data from the table test1 in the database and a button on the right side. If I select a data from the dropdown menu and save it, the data will be displayed to the php table and the id of the selected data will be stored in the child table test2 of the database. The problem is, how?

Please do help me with this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Start by reading the manual on INSERT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you for the link :). Hope it would solve my problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I would recommend you use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*. There are examples on those pages you can start with, then you can Google "prepared statements mysql tutorial", which will yield many results.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That would be awesome. Thank you once again :).

Comment: I'm really stock at my problem... i can't find a solution T.T. please help..